# Flask Rest API not seeing updated table?

Tags: python, mysql, rest, flask

So I have a flask API endpoint that looks something like this

So now the issue im having is, lets say I run the query

```
"Select * from tables where IP = '123'" -> returns "Capacity" : 80
```

However, I then go into my database itself and edit the Capacity to 50. Note: Through the database console itself and not the API.

However the rest API takes 5-10 minutes to see the change in the table! Making the same query within the rest API to the endpoint still returns 80, even though the same query in the table returns 50.

Is there some caching going on within the flask application itself?

Edit: Seems to work fine when I reconnect to the database... hmm

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("address","iuser","pass","table")
cursor = db.cursor()

@app.route('/sqlStatement', methods=['POST'])
def run_statement():
    try:
        statement = request.values['statement']
        try:
            cursor.execute(statement)
        except mysql.connector.Error: #MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
            return "BAD SQL STATEMENT DUMBASS"

        return jsonify(data=cursor.fetchall())

    except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError):
        open_db()
        return run_statement()
```

Answer (score 1):

Was missing a `db.commit()` :)

Noticed this after I used my code to try to insert data, but it worked for reading as well as it maintained database consistency. Turning on auto commit would solve this problem also.